# Pell number factorization and divisibility question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, divisibility, pell-type-equations

In a problem I’m working on, I have positive integers $a,b,c,d$ satisfying
$$
(ab)^2-2(cd)^2=1.  \tag{1}
$$
(So evidently $cd$ is a Pell number, and $ab$ is its companion.) Furthermore, say the following divisibility conditions also hold:
\begin{align}
a &\mid (b^2+2c^2) \\
b &\mid (a^2-2d^2) \\ \tag{2}
c &\mid (a^2+d^2) \\
d &\mid (b^2-c^2).
\end{align}

A brute-force computer search turns up only two solutions so far: $(a,b,c,d)=(3,1,1,2)$ and $(a,b,c,d)=(3,1,2,1)$. I believe they may be the only ones.

I’ve tried to algebraically prove that conjecture, to no avail. From the divisibility system, we see that $a$ must be of the form $x^2+2y^2$, and $c$ must be of the form $u^2+v^2$. From $(1),$ we deduce, for example, that $\gcd(ab,cd)=1$, and also $ab=r^2+2s^2$ (so $b$ is also of that form) and $cd=2rs$ with $r^2-2s^2=\pm1$. But I can’t seem to find the magic combination to complete the proof.

Any hints, assistance, or references would be appreciated.

Comment: The Pell Numbers are 1,2,5,12,29,70,169,408; I find setting $cd$ as 2,12,70,408... gives integer $ab$ as $2^2-1$,$4^2+1$, $10^2-1$,$24^2+1$... respectively.  Can you explain more clearly how you disallowed these other integer solutions? By the way I find setting $cd$ equal to the other alternate Pell numbers 1,5,29,169... gives integer $ab$ when inserted into the equation $(ab)^2-2(cd)^2=-1$

Comment: @JamesArathoon: I ran a program in maxima that tried all $1 \le a,b,c,d \le 100$, and there were no other solutions. I'm upping the upper limit, but even with optimizations (like starting with the Pell numbers, and considering only the complete set of factorizations of the elements), it's a slow process. But I'm confident (because of the problem I'm working on from which these elements were derived) that there are no further solutions.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan - Are you asking for the calculation of all positive integers $a,b,c,d$ satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: A quick search up to $ab=2094232192940929332692027310337$, $cd=1480845785007705294702019308528$ does not reveal any further solutions. The factorisation of the solutions to the pell equations starts to slow down a bit after that. Could you tell us more about the source of the equations (1) and (2) ? It might help to establish a proof that there are no more solutions.

Comment: @hm2020: Yes, exactly that. My conjecture is that $(,,,)=(3,1,1,2)$ and $(,,,)=(3,1,2,1)$ are the only solutions.

Comment: @ArthurVause: With many questions on this site, I’ve observed that giving additional context beyond the stated problem/conjecture often leads to people getting locked into a particular approach to answering the problem — I’d like to avoid that here.

Comment: I found that $(b-c)(a^2-2d^2)<0$.

Comment: @Derivative: (1) How? (2) Did you mean $\le 0$?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan Using the inequalities $a\leq b^2+2c^2$, $b\leq |a^2-2d^2|$, $c\leq a^2+d^2$, $d\leq |b^2-c^2|$. When the two moduli have the same sign you can multiply the first two and last two inequalities together and add them to cancel some terms out. And (2) yes I meant it's less than 0 except for the one solution with $b=c=1$.

Comment: Remark: from (1) and (2) one can, if it helps, derive $(bd)^2 \equiv 1\pmod a$ and $(ac)^2\equiv-1\pmod b$ and $(bd)^2\equiv-1\pmod c$ and $(ac)^2\equiv1\pmod d$. In particular, $a,b,c,d$ are pairwise relatively prime.

Comment: @Arthur Vause I would be curious how many times you found that either the larger of a, b or the larger of c, d met the divisibility condition. So one condition was  met instead of four.

Comment: @gnasher729 An interesting set of results for the larger of a,b and the larger of c,d. The vast majority of results are where the smaller of a,b = 1 or the smaller of c,d = 1.  Apart for a small number of results for $(x_3,y_3), (x_6,y_6), (x_9,y_9)$, the only other results occur for odd values of $k$ when $x_k$ is of the form $m^2-1$, and the values $(a,b) = (m+1,m-1)$ or $(a,b) = (m-1,m+1)$.   Results here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldFWhK1Dm83roP-1oRYT59RLdUNt-Ps9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ArthurVause: This is the most helpful response so far. Please post that information (with any extra details you have) as an answer, so I can award you the bounty.

Comment: You know, Kieran, when you write, "I have determined that...," it looks like you are saying, "I have proved that...." It doesn't look like you are saying, "I want to impose the following additional conditions...." Maybe if you wrote the question more carefully, you wouldn't have half-a-dozen people getting the wrong idea. Please edit the body of the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Excellent point — my bad. I hope my edit makes it sufficiently clear, and I will strive to ask questions more helpfully in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prompted by a suggestion from @gnasher729 I have analysed the solutions to (1) that satisfy one or more of (2) where the larger of a,b or the larger of c,d divides the relevant expression of (2).

Defining $(x_k, y_k)$ to be the k-th solution to $x^2-2y^2=1$,

so for $k=0$ to $5$, $(x_k, y_k) =  (1,0), (3, 2),(17, 12),(99, 70),(577, 408),(3363, 2378) $

The vast majority of results are where the smaller of a,b = 1 or the smaller of c,d = 1.

Apart for a small number of results for $(x_3,y_3),(x_6,y_6),(x_9,y_9)$, the only other results occur for odd values of k when $x_k$ is of the form $m^2−1$, and $(a,b)=(m+1,m−1)$ or $(m−1,m+1)$.

Results are available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldFWhK1Dm83roP-1oRYT59RLdUNt-Ps9/view

I terminated the search at $k=75$, not because the factorisation of $x_k$ and $y_k$ is difficult, bu simply because the number of divisors was very large, giving over 2 billion combinations of $a,b,c,d$

The "erratic" solutions for $k=3,6,9$ are:

k = 3, (x,y) = (99, 70):

large d divides b^2 - c^2, (a,b,c,d)=  (3, 33, 2, 35)
large d divides b^2 - c^2, (a,b,c,d)=  (3, 33, 5, 14)
large d divides b^2 - c^2, (a,b,c,d)=  (3, 33, 7, 10)
large d divides b^2 - c^2, (a,b,c,d)=  (33, 3, 7, 10)

k = 6, (x,y) = (19601, 13860):

large d divides b^2 - c^2, (a,b,c,d)=  (1153, 17, 28, 495)

large d divides b^2 - c^2, (a,b,c,d)=  (17, 1153, 35, 396)

k = 9, (x,y) = (3880899, 2744210):

large d divides b^2 - c^2, (a,b,c,d)=  (179, 21681, 985, 2786)

Comment: Do you think there’s a way to identify all of the “small number of results” that aren’t of the form $m^2-1$? This is a very promising direction.

Comment: Another approach might be to prove that there aren't any $a,b$ values that satisfy both $a | (b^2+2c^2)$ and $b | (a^2-2d^2)$ that aren't of the form $(a,b) = (1,x), (x,1) (m-1,m+1), (m+1,m-1)$, as I haven't found any erratics where $a$ or $b$ are the divisors.

Comment: One implication of is that $a \mid (b^2d^2-1)$ and $b \mid (a^2c^2+1)$. Still trying to find the QED…

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**
Incomplete solution.

From $(1)$ it is clear that $ab$ is odd.
$$\begin{aligned}(ab)^2-2(cd)^2=1 \quad &\Longleftrightarrow \quad (ab)^2-1=2(cd)^2\\&\Longleftrightarrow \quad (\underbrace{ab-1}_{2k})(\underbrace{ab+1}_{2k+2})=2(cd)^2, \end{aligned} \tag{*}$$
it follows that $cd$ is even.

- Assume that $cd$ is a power of $2.$ Then $(*)$ rewrites
  $$4k(k+1)=2^{2n+1},$$ which is only possible if $k=1.$ Taking into account $(2),$ this gives the two solutions you already found.
- In general, $(*)$ simplifies to
  $$2k(k+1)=(cd)^2.$$
  Let $p\neq 2$ be a prime. Between two consecutive numbers, at most one is divisible by $p.$ However, one of them can be divisible by $p^{2},$ as pointed out by Arthur Vause.

  - As an example, $k=8$ satisfies and gives  $$(a,b,c,d), \; \text{where}\; ab=17 \;\text{ and} \;cd=12.$$ However, $(2)$ is not checked.
  - A different family of solutions could be obtained when $k=49.$ Here $$(a,b,c,d) \; \text{are such that}\; ab=99 \;\text{ and} \;cd=70.$$

Comment: You have overlooked the possibility that for an odd prime $p$,   $p^2$ can be a factor of $ab-1$ or $ab+1$

Comment: @ArthurVause you are right, I did not consider it. I can see clearly further solutions (EDIT) but do not have a complete proof for the moment.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question. I have ($1$), but _separately_ (i.e., _additionally_) I have the divisibility requirements ($2$). Your alleged solutions don’t satisfy ($2$), right? _e.g.,_ none of the possible factorizations of $ab=99$ and $cd=70$ satisfy (2).

Comment: @KierenMacMillan Original formulation of the question was quite missleading. That causes inappropriet solutions and downvotes to them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem $x^2 - 2y^2 = + / - 1$ is well known: the first solutions are (1, 0), (1, 1), (3, 2), (7, 5), (17, 12) etc. with (x, y) followed by (x + 2y, x + y). The recurrence can be reversed, so you get from one solution to the previous one, which shows that there are no other solutions.

With this sequence the remainder alternates between 1 and -1, so we take every second term (1, 0), (3, 2), (17, 12), (99, 70) etc. with (x, y) followed by (3x + 4y, 2x+3y).

Factoring x, y gives you a, b, c, d so you can check your other conditions. x grows slightly more than a factor 5.8 from one solution to the next (factor is about 3 + sqrt 8), so you should find all solutions that you can factor in reasonable time quite quickly; there are about 50 pairs (x, y) less than $2^{128}$.

The chance that one of a, b, c, d divide a random integer is 1/a, 1/b, 1/c, 1/d. The chance of all four dividing four random integers is 1/xy. So this is very unlikely to happen unless you find a reason why they should divide. The chance for (17, 12) is only one in 204 and things get worse quickly.